# Insert HTML table into OpenXML

Tags: c#, fonts, openxml, html-table

We've got a SharePoint2010 site having a custom functionality to generate a word document containing information gathered dynamically from the contained list items.
Info is being gathered from the SP site and replaced in a word document containing content controls. The entire word document generation process works besides some font issues. 
We want to insert a HTML table into the document in order to keep some rich text formatting which can be set by the end user in the SP site. If a cell content is being inserted instead, the rich text formatting isn't being interpreted, but shown as plain text (which we obviously don't want).

**Issue**: When inserting text into the word document (into an SdtBlock, SdtCell or SdtRun element), the default font defined in the Word template for the Normal style is being applied. When inserting a html table, these settings are being discarded.

First, how it looks in the word document (the table is being generated without the grid lines which I've added for better visualization):
[image: table in word document]

Here's an example of the HTML source table being added to the document.

```
<table width="100%" border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <tr style="font-weight:bold;font-style:italic">
        <td/>
        <td/>
        <td style="padding-right:2px;">Traktandum</td>
        <td style="padding-right:2px;">Wer</td>
        <td style="padding-right:2px;" width=100>Wann</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#D8D8D8;" style="font-weight:bold" >
        <td width=25 style="padding-left:5px">1.</td>
        <td colspan=4>Begrüssung</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td valign="top">1.1</td>
        <td valign="top">g1 (VR-IV)</td>
        <td valign="top" />
        <td valign="top" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td/>
        <td style="font-family:Arial;">
            <em class="ms-rteFontSize-4">
                <strong>Zusatztext</strong>
            </em>
        </td>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td/>
        <td>
            <strong class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-5-4 ms-rteFontSize-4" style="text-decoration: underline">
                <em>Protokoll Eintrag</em>
            </strong>
        </td>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td/>
        <td  style="font-weight:bold;color:red">Bemerkung</td>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td/>
        <td valign="top" height=140 colspan=2><ul><li></li></ul>
        </td>
        <td/>
        <td/>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Which results in following content in the document part of the OpenXML document

```
<w:tbl>
  <w:tblPr>
    <w:tblW w:w="5000" w:type="pct" />
    <w:tblCellSpacing w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
    <w:tblCellMar>
      <w:left w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
      <w:right w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
    </w:tblCellMar>
    <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1" />
  </w:tblPr>
  <w:tblGrid>
    <w:gridCol w:w="375" />
    <w:gridCol w:w="1045" />
    <w:gridCol w:w="6053" />
    <w:gridCol w:w="1523" />
    <w:gridCol w:w="1500" />
  </w:tblGrid>
  <w:tr w:rsidR="00000000" w14:paraId="4CF55392" w14:textId="77777777">
    <w:trPr>
      <w:divId w:val="102891968" />
      <w:tblCellSpacing w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="41FC7D09" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
            <w:i />
            <w:iCs />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="0E55AB8C" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
            <w:i />
            <w:iCs />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:tcMar>
          <w:top w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
          <w:left w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
          <w:bottom w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
          <w:right w:w="30" w:type="dxa" />
        </w:tcMar>
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="07A2D535" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
            <w:i />
            <w:iCs />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
            <w:i />
            <w:iCs />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>Traktandum</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:tcMar>
          <w:top w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
          <w:left w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
          <w:bottom w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
          <w:right w:w="30" w:type="dxa" />
        </w:tcMar>
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="0CDA0057" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
            <w:i />
            <w:iCs />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
            <w:i />
            <w:iCs />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>Wer</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="1500" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:tcMar>
          <w:top w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
          <w:left w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
          <w:bottom w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
          <w:right w:w="30" w:type="dxa" />
        </w:tcMar>
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="224BB1EB" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
            <w:i />
            <w:iCs />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
            <w:i />
            <w:iCs />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>Wann</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
  <w:tr w:rsidR="00000000" w14:paraId="62BFC5EF" w14:textId="77777777">
    <w:trPr>
      <w:divId w:val="102891968" />
      <w:tblCellSpacing w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="375" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:tcMar>
          <w:top w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
          <w:left w:w="75" w:type="dxa" />
          <w:bottom w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
          <w:right w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
        </w:tcMar>
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="7A93E1A6" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>1.</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:gridSpan w:val="4" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="1644A6CD" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>Begrüssung</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
  <w:tr w:rsidR="00000000" w14:paraId="472509E4" w14:textId="77777777">
    <w:trPr>
      <w:divId w:val="102891968" />
      <w:tblCellSpacing w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="72195C41" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="51F5222C" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>1.1</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="442CD5DD" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>g1 (VR-IV)</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="07155E00" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="59C3C9E4" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
  <w:tr w:rsidR="00000000" w14:paraId="71612A68" w14:textId="77777777">
    <w:trPr>
      <w:divId w:val="102891968" />
      <w:tblCellSpacing w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="72F95667" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="6274A0CE" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="2F49F48D" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rStyle w:val="Strong" />
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:i />
            <w:iCs />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>Zusatztext</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="43378669" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="442C4508" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
  <w:tr w:rsidR="00000000" w14:paraId="1608D15F" w14:textId="77777777">
    <w:trPr>
      <w:divId w:val="102891968" />
      <w:tblCellSpacing w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="37A4C434" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="4707D270" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="1220DA79" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rStyle w:val="Emphasis" />
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
            <w:u w:val="single" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>Protokoll Eintrag</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="116A07E3" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="2BBD3E39" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
  <w:tr w:rsidR="00000000" w14:paraId="740FCC38" w14:textId="77777777">
    <w:trPr>
      <w:divId w:val="102891968" />
      <w:tblCellSpacing w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="6B54F9FB" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="36071589" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="48D1EC48" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
            <w:color w:val="FF0000" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:b />
            <w:bCs />
            <w:color w:val="FF0000" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>Bemerkung</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="386252E2" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="2F1281F1" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
  <w:tr w:rsidR="00000000" w14:paraId="5FB6D8FB" w14:textId="77777777">
    <w:trPr>
      <w:divId w:val="102891968" />
      <w:trHeight w:val="2100" />
      <w:tblCellSpacing w:w="0" w:type="dxa" />
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="1D1A8019" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:gridSpan w:val="2" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="1CB10D62" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="0" />
            <w:numId w:val="38" />
          </w:numPr>
          <w:spacing w:before="100" w:beforeAutospacing="1" w:after="100" w:afterAutospacing="1" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="4F5B3B52" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
        <w:hideMark />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="001C1B56" w14:paraId="79FFA701" w14:textId="77777777">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:eastAsia="Times New Roman" />
            <w:sz w:val="24" />
            <w:szCs w:val="24" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
</w:tbl>
```

w:sz is 24, which corresponds to font size 11 in the Word document

When inserting text NOT being part of a table, following is being found in the OpenXML document:

```
<w:tc>
  <w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="8647" w:type="dxa" />
    <w:gridSpan w:val="2" />
  </w:tcPr>
  <w:p w:rsidRPr="003758CE" w:rsidR="003758CE" w:rsidP="0027263A" w:rsidRDefault="003758CE" w14:paraId="50577C90" w14:textId="1FA19C31">
    <w:pPr>
      <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="20" />
        <w:szCs w:val="20" />
      </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="003758CE">
      <w:rPr>
        <w:sz w:val="20" />
        <w:szCs w:val="20" />
      </w:rPr>
      <w:t>Teilnehmende, VRP</w:t>
    </w:r>
  </w:p>
</w:tc>
```

w:sz is 20, which corresponds to font size 10 in the Word document

Comment: The example xml is helpful - but can you post the openxml code that shows how you do the inserting a html table into your document?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use altchunks for adding Html data to the document and need to open and save the document to get open xml markup from html.
See this in detail here. [Add HTML String to OpenXML (*.docx) Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089921/add-html-string-to-openxml-docx-document)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It turned out that the mistake was on my side. The template word file had a font set for a field which was overriding the Normal font. The implementation is actually working as expected. Thanks anyway :)