# Create document using docx library with HTML text

Tags: c#, novacode-docx

I want to create a document (*.docx) using docx library. I have HTML formatted text from a rich text editor, and I want to save it as it is. I am not able to find any place where I can get the help. My current code is very basic, and is copy paste from there help.

My code looks like:

```
private string CreateDocumentFromText()
{
    string filePath= Server.MapPath("../DocXExample.docx");
    var document = Novacode.DocX.Create(filePath);
    document.InsertParagraph("<b>Test</b>");            
    document.Save();
    return fileName;
}
```

Document has content as:

```
 <b>Test</b>
```

Whereas I want it to be:

**Test**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert it to xml element.
Try DocumentFormat.OpenXml library

Comment: Can you point to some example, because when I looked for it, I found that I will have to insert it as external content, but then user experience will not be same as inserting the text in word format. Any idea?

Comment: I found the solution in another thread [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089921/add-html-string-to-openxml-docx-document)